# Get return value from ucontext as it terminates

Tags: c, pthreads, ucontext

I am implementing a user-level thread lib using `ucontext_t`. I am linking threads to the scheduler thread via `uc_link`, however, we need to get the return value on some occasions. I don't know how to get the return value as the contexts are separate.
The only way I can think of accessing the return value is by somehow going to the stack of that context and finding where the return value would be. However, this seems like a formula for disaster and weird errors.

Comment: What return value?  The entry-point function set via `makecontext()` returns `void`, so it has no return value.  You reap undefined behavior if you instead pass a function that returns a value.

Comment: Also, what does pthreads have to do with this?  Writing your own thread library implies that you are *avoiding* pthreads.

Comment: I meant that whatever function the thread may execute may want to return a value and if there was a way of capturing that value. However, I see that it is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get return value from ucontext as it terminates

An execution context such as is represented by `ucontext_t` has no return value.  This is implicit in the behavior when the entry-point function terminates (the successor context, if any, is activated), and explicit in the signature of the entry-point function (it returns `void`).

Note also that the entry-point function must additionally be non-variadic, unlike `makecontext()` itself, though it can take any fixed number of arguments.  The caller of `makecontext` is obligated to specify the correct argument count and that many `int` arguments.

If you want to communicate data between contexts then you should write it or a pointer to it in some shared memory location from which you can later, in a different context, retrieve it.  Presumably, in this case that would be somewhere in the metadata that your lib maintains for each thread.

If the data in question are the return value of some function, then that function cannot be the context's entry-point.  In that case (and for other reasons, too) you may want to avoid using functions provided by the user as ucontext entry points.  Instead, use a function provided internally by the library that knows how to bootstrap to the user function and what to do when it returns.